# makestagram - swift list post in table view ordered from newest to old

Tags: ios, swift, social-media

Hi everyone Im practice swift by Makeschool's makestagram project,
and I want to make the newest post appear at the top of a table view
to let user can see the newest post first!

can anyone help?
here is my code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timelineComponent = TimelineComponent(target: self)
    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self



        }

  func takePhoto(){
    // instantiate photo taking class, provide callback for when photo  is selected
    photoTakingHelper = PhotoTakingHelper(viewController: self.tabBarController!,callback:{ (image: UIImage?)in
        let post = Post()
        post.image.value = image!

        post.uploadPost()
        }

    )

}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
timelineComponent.loadInitialIfRequired()
            }

func loadInRange(range: Range<Int>, completionBlock: ([Post]?) -> Void) {

ParseHelper.timelineRequestForCurrentUser(range) {
    (result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
    ErrorHandling.defaultErrorHandler(error)
    }


    let posts = result as? [Post] ?? []


    completionBlock(posts)
}
```

}

}

```
    extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.timelineComponent.content.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell")as! PostTableViewCell
    let post = timelineComponent.content[indexPath.section]
    post.downloadImage()
    post.fetchLikes()
    cell.post = post



    return cell

}
```

}

```
   extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDelegate{
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    timelineComponent.targetWillDisplayEntry(indexPath.section)

}
      func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostHeader")as! PostSectionHeaderView
    let post = self.timelineComponent.content[section]
    headerCell.post = post
    return headerCell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

}

Comment: This is a [Does Not Work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) post.  You have not sufficiently described your problem, and as such, if you do not [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36970324/edit) to describe your problem, your question will likely be put on hold.  I'd recommend working on an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: on the top of all the post, list from newest to old one!

Comment: If self.posts is the data source for the table then it should work as you are adding it at the front of the array, as it doesn't work then there's something else going on, so you need to show more relevant code.

Comment: thanks for your advice I have change the way to describe my question!
English is not my native language,  so my grammar might not correct, sorry for misunderstanding!

Comment: You need to show more code, in particular cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I have already use reverse() and insert.(post, at index:0) but it didn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out!

parse's PFquery got updatedAt method

I change createdAt to updatedAt.

Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Well done. On a side note, Now do you see any problems with your post? You never once mentioned you were using parse nor did you include any code which was querying parse backend for data. In future, for debugging help, always give a moment to think of potentially problematic areas and brief others clearly about your problem.

Comment: Got it ! thanks for your kind advice, I learn much from it! Next time I will do much better.